# Webmock stub request with any body and header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, webmock

How to use Webmock to stub request with any body and header? I tried to use regex

```
WebMock.stub_request(:post, 'api.quickblox.com/').with(:body => /.*?/, :headers => /.*?/).to_return(:status => 201, :body => "", :headers => {})
```

in rspec but it doesn't work, it has

```
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `map' for /.*?/:Regexp
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out the [`Webmock` docs on `headers`](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock#matching-request-body-and-headers-against-regular-expressions). You need to provide it a hash with further details on what you are matching.

Comment: Also see the [matching headers](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock#matching-headers) section.

Answer (score 17):

You should be able to just use

```
WebMock.stub_request(:post, 'api.quickblox.com/')
  .to_return(status: 201, body: 'whatever', headers: { some_kind_of: 'header' })
```

If you don't specify the body or headers on the stub itself, it will allow anything for the body or headers. This does not apply to query parameters.

For example, this sample project's test passes:

`bundle exec rspec` output:

```
Test
  does a thing

Finished in 0.00379 seconds (files took 0.25797 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

lib/test.rb

```
require 'faraday'
require 'json'

class Test
  def self.do_a_thing
    JSON.parse(Faraday.get('http://www.example.com') do |request|
      request.headers['Something'] = 'anything'
      request.body = 'bla bla bla'
    end.body)
  end
end
```

spec/test_spec.rb

```
require_relative '../lib/test.rb'
require 'webmock/rspec'

describe Test do
  WebMock.stub_request(:get, 'http://www.example.com')
    .to_return(body: '{ "this": "is a test" }')

  it 'does a thing' do
    expect(described_class.do_a_thing).to include({ 'this' => 'is a test' })
  end
end
```

.ruby-version

```
ruby-2.0.0
```

Gemfile

```
gem 'rspec'
gem 'webmock'
gem 'faraday'
```

Gemfile.lock

```
GEM
  specs:
    addressable (2.3.8)
    crack (0.4.2)
      safe_yaml (~> 1.0.0)
    diff-lcs (1.2.5)
    faraday (0.9.1)
      multipart-post (>= 1.2, < 3)
    multipart-post (2.0.0)
    rspec (3.2.0)
      rspec-core (~> 3.2.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.2.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.2.0)
    rspec-core (3.2.3)
      rspec-support (~> 3.2.0)
    rspec-expectations (3.2.1)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.2.0)
    rspec-mocks (3.2.1)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.2.0)
    rspec-support (3.2.2)
    safe_yaml (1.0.4)
    webmock (1.20.4)
      addressable (>= 2.3.6)
      crack (>= 0.3.2)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  faraday
  rspec
  webmock

BUNDLED WITH
   1.10.5
```

Comment: This is not true, it will not match.

Comment: Yeah. It should work. I thought it didn't, either, but then I realized I actually had never called `stub_request`

Comment: BEWARE OF THE TRAILING SLASH on the url! stub_request(:get, ' h ttp://www.example.com') will match anything, but stub_request(:get, ' h ttp://www.example.com/') won't!! Lost some time on this.

Comment: Make sure that the URLs match exactly. If you aren't specifying a protocol in your expectation, it will default to `http`.