# Having issue with webmock in stubbing request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, exotel-api

I am writin specs for my gem and I am using webmock to mock http requests. But i keep on getting this weird error.

Here is my specs code

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'Generator::Exotel' do

  describe '#success' do
    let(:resps) { {"Status"=>"200", "Message"=>"Success"} }

    before do
      stub_request(:post, "https://test_sid:test_token@twilix.exotel.in/v1/Accounts/#{Generator::configuration.sid}/Sms/send").
        with(:body => {:To => 1234, :Body => "test sms"}, :headers => {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'}).
          to_return(:body => resps.to_json, :headers => {})
    end

    it 'returns response object for success' do
      response = Generator::Exotel.send(:to => 1234, :body => "test sms")
      expect(response.to_json).to eq (resps.to_json)
    end
  end  

  describe '#failure' do
    let(:resp) { {"Status"=>"401", "Message"=>"Not Authenticated"} }

    before do
      stub_request(:post, "https://test_sid:test_token@twilix.exotel.in/v1/Accounts/#{Generator::configuration.sid}/Sms/send").
        with(:body => {:To => 1234, :Body => "test sms"}, :headers => {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'}).
          to_return(:body=> resp.to_json, :headers => {})
    end

    it 'returns response object for failure' do
      response = Generator::Exotel.send(:to => 1234, :body => "test sms")
      expect(response.to_json).to eq (resp.to_json)
    end
  end
end
```

Whenever i run `rspec`, i am getting this following error

```
Generator::Exotel #success returns response object for success
     Failure/Error: response = self.class.post("/#{Generator::configuration.sid}/Sms/send",  {:body => params, :basic_auth => auth })

     WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError:
       Real HTTP connections are disabled. Unregistered request: POST https://twilix.exotel.in/v1/Accounts/test_sid/Sms/send with body 'To=1234&Body=test%20sms' with headers {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3', 'Authorization'=>'Basic dGVzdF9zaWQ6dGVzdF90b2tlbg==', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'}

       You can stub this request with the following snippet:

       stub_request(:post, "https://twilix.exotel.in/v1/Accounts/test_sid/Sms/send").
         with(:body => "To=1234&Body=test%20sms",
              :headers => {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3', 'Authorization'=>'Basic dGVzdF9zaWQ6dGVzdF90b2tlbg==', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'}).
         to_return(:status => 200, :body => "", :headers => {})

       registered request stubs:

       stub_request(:post, "https://test_sid:test_token@twilix.exotel.in/v1/Accounts/test_sid/Sms/send").
         with(:body => {"Body"=>"test sms", "To"=>1234},
              :headers => {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'})

       ============================================================
```

I have googled a lot and found some solutions, i.e,

[Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23159588/webmock-stub-request-with-any-body-and-header)

[Relish Documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/webmock/webmock/docs/stubbing/stubbing-requests)

[“WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980856/trying-to-get-selenium-working-in-rails-3-webmocknetconnectnotallowederror)

Also i had a look at this [post](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-to-stub-external-services-in-tests) , But in vain.

Also i tried using `WebMock.disable_net_connect!(:allow_localhost => true)`
but got the same result. Anyone know what am i doing wrong? I am really new to ruby and for first time i am writing specs and its really confusing me.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make external http requests with webmock, as rightly said by various posts that you mentioned. I notice your stubbed urls have interpolated variables in them ie `"https://test_sid:test_token@twilix.exotel.in/v1/Accounts/#{Generator::configuration.sid}/Sms/send"`. You need to:

1. Make sure `Generator::configuration.sid` is accessible within the specs
2. If it's not accessible then just return a plain url which is perfectly fine

Comment: yes `Generator::configuration.sid` is accessible within specs, but its still not working and i tried with plain url also and got the same error.

Comment: well thanks for reply, i figured out what was the problem. it was my response that i am returning, not the url. anyways +1 for reply.